# Change Id type of asp.net core 2.2 IdentityUser

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm new to dot-net core 2.x, so...

I would like to change the type of the Id in asp.net core 2.2 IdentityUser from string to int.

All the examples I've found via google (and the stackoverflow search facility) are giving me examples of asp.net core 2.0 which provides an ApplicationUser when you scaffold Identity (which 2.2 did not provide).

SO, I'm at a loss..  The first thing I tried (which I had high hopes for) was:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser<int>>()
  .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
  .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
  .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

But, I get the following error when I try to Add-Migration InitialCreate -Context ApplicationDbContext:

> An error occurred while accessing the IWebHost on class 'Program'. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: GenericArguments[0], 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser`1[System.Int32]', on 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9[TUser,TRole,TContext,TKey,TUserClaim,TUserRole,TUserLogin,TUserToken,TRoleClaim]' violates the constraint of type 'TUser'

Thoughts? Ideas? Documentation I can read?

Comment: @TanvirArjel I've rolled back your edit that makes it look like the OP asked to also change the type of the Role type, seeing as how that was not the case.

Answer (score 16):

For changing IdentityUser key type from string to int, you also need to change the `IdentityDbContext` to `IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser<int>,IdentityRole<int>,int>`.

1. Startup.cs

   ```
   services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser<int>>()
       .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
       .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
   ```
2. `ApplicationDbContext`

   ```
   public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser<int>,IdentityRole<int>,int>
   {
       public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
           : base(options)
       {
       }
   }
   ```
3. Remove `Migrations` folder and delete the existing database
4. Run command to add and update the database

Comment: When I add ".AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)"  in Identity, it is giving me error "The name UIFramweork does not exist in current context". What should I download or install for this?

Comment: @CrazyCoder `.AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)` is in the .net core 2.2 template.

Comment: The command from the package manager console is *Add-Migration* e.g `Add-Migration AspIdentity` To apply the changes to your database: `Update-Database` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/

Comment: I would also recommend you reading [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-3.1#change-the-primary-key-type) for instructions for making it work with SignInManager and other Idenitty services seamsly.

Answer (score 8):

You can write your own implementation that derives from `IdentityUser`

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser<int> 
{

}
```

Then register it:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<AppUser>()
```

This is also useful if you want to add additional properties to your user model.

Remember that because you are changing primary key of the tables, so you will need to recreate these tables instead of updating them.

Comment: Ok, there must be something missing because this doesn't work. When I create my migration the ID on User is still a string.

Comment: @djack109 Maybe you've previously built the tables with `string` type instead of `int` type. Try deleting all of you migrations and creating it from scratch with the type as `int`. If this doesn't work, then please create a new question with [mcve]

Comment: When I create the database it still has a datatype of nvarchar(450) rather than int. Any idea how to get it to create an int Primary Key in the database itself? thx.