# How to change AspNetUsers.Id type to int when using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I created *ASP.NET core Web App C#* project with Individual Accounts in VS2022 [image]

The database created by Entity Framework by the DB conext contained in the project contains table `AspNetUsers` with primary key `Id` which has data type `nvarchar(450)`. The id column contais GUID created for each registered user. As a part of adapting an existing database for *Identity.UI* I need to change the primary key type to `int`. I have attempted to adapt a solution from [ASP.Net.Core 2.2 Identity change ID from string to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58147591) and [Change Id type of asp.net core 2.2 IdentityUser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53749631).

I have modified the DatatContext

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser<int>, IdentityRole<int>, int>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

and have modified services configuration

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser<int>>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

The problem is that I am getting

```
InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' has been registered.
```

in *_Layout.cshtml*.

**Do I miss something or does .net 6 need some completely different approach?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that is necessary to modify `_LoginPartial.cshtml`, where is necessary to change `IdentityUser` to `IdentityUser<int>`.
At the begining of `_LoginPartial.cshtml` which was created when the new project was created we have

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager
```

The problem is that we have added a generic idenity `.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser<int>>`, and so is also necessary to inject SignInManager and UserManager for the generic identity

```
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser<int>> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser<int>> UserManager
```

and that is it and it is possible to register a new user and log in.